# preg_match regex, find text within link

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im looking to 'preg_match' a link that looks like /dp/B0039SD7S6/blah-blah my current expression looks like...

```
$var = preg_match('/dp\/(.?*)\//', $output);
```

This doesn't output '039SD7S6'. Im assuming because the backslashes interfere with the delimiter. Help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: `/\/dp\/(.?*)\//`.  try escaping it

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that. It didn't seem to work. Thanks for the input. I just added that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 problems with your regex:

- yes, the slash, you have to escape it or change delimiters;
- ungreedy option: `?` must be after `.*`
- `preg_match` syntax: result must be in parameters, not in returning value.

Change in this way:

```
 preg_match('/dp\/(.*?)\//', $output, $var);
```

Or - as I prefer - in this way:

```
preg_match('{dp/(.*?)/}', $output, $var);
```

---

- See more about [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- See more about [Regular expression syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: Hadn't known you could use the curly braces to enclose regex patterns. Good to know.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 You can use any character if not included in the pattern.